# Input doesn't go to while -loop

Tags: c

I am having trouble of getting a user input and go to the switch loop, but it keeps saying invalid answer which is the default option.

For example, a main menu appear to select a choice. Then the use would select a choice which should go to the switch loop, but I keep recieving default answer which is "this is an invalid response". I don't understand what would be the issue in here.

```
int main() {
// Asking user to put the size of an array
int sel, c1, c2, found, size;
sel = 0;
printf("Please choose the size of your input: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
int arr[size];

while(sel != '4'){
    //Main Function
    printf("This is the main function. Selected choice below \n");
    printf("1. See the data. \n");
    printf("2. Select the data. \n");
    printf("3. Count the data. \n");
    printf("4. Quit Main Menu. \n");
    scanf("%d", &sel);
    
    switch(sel){
        case '1':
            fillArray(arr,size);
            printf("Thank you, you have selected enter the data \n");
            break;
            
        case '2':
            // Searching Arrays and pointers
            printf("Select choice below: \n");
            printf("1. Array \n");
            printf("2. Pointers \n");
            scanf("%d", &c1);
            
            // Searching number using array
            if (c1 == '1')
            {
                printf("You have select an array search \n");
                printf("Enter the number to search: \n");
                scanf("%d", &found);
                
                int arraySearch = searchArr(arr,size,found);
                printf("This number is in the index: %d \n", arraySearch);
                
            }
            
            // Searching number using pointers
            else if (c1 == '2')
            {
                int ptrSearch = 0;
                printf("You have select a pointer search \n");
                printf("Enter the number to search: \n");
                scanf("%d", &found);
                
                ptrSearch = searchPtr(arr, size, found);
                printf("This number is in the index: %d \n", ptrSearch);

            }
            
            else
            {
                printf("You have selected an invalid response \n");
            }
            break;
            
        case '3':
            // Counting Array and pointers
            printf("Select choice below: \n");
            printf("1. Array \n");
            printf("2. Pointers \n");
            scanf("%d", &c2);
            
            int check = 0;
            // Searching number using array
            if (c2 == '1')
            {
                printf("You have select using count with array \n");
                printf("Enter the number you want to count: \n");
                scanf("%d", &check);
                
                int arrayCount = countArr(arr,size,check);
                printf("This number is found in here: %d \n", arrayCount);
                
            }
            
            // Counting number using pointers
            else if (c2 == '2')
            {
                int ptrCount = 0;
                printf("You have select counting numbers using pointers \n");
                printf("Enter the number to to count: \n");
                scanf("%d", &check);
                
                ptrCount = countPtr(arr, size, check);
                printf("This number is found in here: %d \n", ptrCount);

            }
            
            else
            {
                printf("You have selected an invalid response \n");
            }
            break;
            
        case '4':
            printf("Thank you for using this prgroam \n");
            printf("Exiting now");
            break;
            
        default:
            printf("This is an invalid response. \n");
            printf("Please select another number. \n");
        break;
            
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: In `case` you are using characters instead of integers. That's whats causing the conditional  statement to move to `default`.

Comment: Please fix a [mre]. You cannot possibly need so many lines to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: Replace characters in `case` to integers. E.g. `case '1'` to `case 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable sel is used as character in switch cases, but it is declared as int. Need to use it as int in switch cases too.
Just use 1,2,3,4 instead of '1','2','3','4' in switch cases.

Best Regards,
Haridas.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a character with an integer like this.
This code will compare the ASCII value of the character with the input integer.
So, you need to change

`case '1' :`

`case '2' :`
and so on into

`case 1 :`

`case 2 :`
and so on...